# Компилятор не видит заголовочный файл

Tags: c++, visual-studio

У меня проблема , создаю класс средством Visual Studio. При подключении заголовка компилятор ругается мол файла нету такого, но когда прописываю полный путь к файлу, то всё хорошо.А вот если пишу `#include <Dragonborn\Binary.h>` или `#include <Binary.h>` то файла не видно. На скрине видно что файлы лежат в одной папке

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А в кавычках, а не `<>`, указывать имя не пробовали?...

Answer (score 1):

1. Для файлов, расположенных по нестандартным путям, надо использовать не угловые скобки, а кавычки.
2. Использовать абсолютные пути - обычно так себе идея.
3. Возможно, в кавычках придётся удвоить обратный слеш. Но я бы просто заменил его на прямой.

Comment: 4. Надо инклюдить пути в проекте, чтобы не писать пути

Comment: @Andrey, чем отличается от 2?

Comment: ну можно писать #include "include/badcode.h" а можно заинклюдиться сабдиром (например в CMake) и писать  #include "badcode.h"

Comment: @Andrey, а, про такое я вообще не в курсе был.